# Поворот на 90 градусов

Tags: android, java

Мне нужно разместить текст и картинку вертикально. Вот так:

[image]

То есть чтобы всё было повернуто на 90 градусов влево. Как это сделать?

Comment: Ответ в [этой теме](http://hashcode.ru/questions/107424).

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант через `RotateAnimation`

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="0"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="0"
    android:toDegrees="-90" >
</rotate>
```

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы вьюшка сразу отображалась вертикально, без анимации?

Comment: дык без анимации же,не?
android:duration="0"

Comment: У меня все равно немного анимирует.