# Вертикальный текст в Android

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток. Хотел бы узнать рациональный способ вертикального отображения текста. Нагуглить удалось вариант с рисованием на конве и использование анимации поворота.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мне [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/79024/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-90-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2) тоже когда-то так посоветовали делать. Но я решил этот вопрос по-другому:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(activity) { 
  @Override 
  protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) { 
    super.onMeasure(heightSpec, widthSpec); 
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth()); 
  } 

  @Override 
  protected boolean setFrame(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) { 
    super.setFrame(left, top, left + (bottom - top), top + (right - left)); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public void draw(Canvas canvas) { 
    canvas.translate(0, getWidth()); 
    canvas.rotate(-90); 
    canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), Op.REPLACE); 
    super.draw(canvas); 
  }        
};
```

Comment: спасибо, мне как раз надо было в одном приложении осуществлять вращение, причём чтобы и bounding box тоже вращался. А при стандартной анимации вращается только вид вьюхи а кликабельная область остаётся прежней

Answer (score 0):

В принципе тоже, что и выше, но вот готовый класс:

```
public class VerticalTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{

public VerticalTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightSpec, widthSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}

@Override
protected boolean setFrame(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.setFrame(left, top, left + (bottom - top), top + (right - left));
    return true;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.translate(0, getWidth());
    canvas.rotate(-90);
    canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), Region.Op.REPLACE);
    super.draw(canvas);
}
```

}